# mp3 url's won't play

Tags: macos, laptop, macbook, mp3

I'm on a macbook and when useing firefox, MP3's called up from a public url don't load or play anymore. They used to. I'm just looking at a blank screen with the copied url on the tab. But they play fine on Chrome. What's up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the mp3 player with that file type within Firefox's settings.

*updated to add link:* http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/quicktime-plugin-play-audio-and-video

Comment: It may be helpful to the OP (and your rating) if you provide a quick how-to / link & summary.  It's more fitting of the format on SU.